# How to implement different authentication strategies in an Express app, without using Passport.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

My situation demands to implement an authentication mechanism in my express app (my stack is MERN) without using any 3rd party middleware for authentication (like passport.js). I have to implement many authentication strategies like Google, Facebook, local login, etc. What should be the folder/project structure and how to do it correctly for it to be scalable if more strategies come up later?

Comment: There is no specific/suggested folder structure for nodejs app. It's completely up to you how you can manage your stuff.

Comment: I agree. Just asking what would be the recommended approach by you.